# progress tracking of multiple async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-5.0

There is a method which gets a server response with

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

There's additional code to set up the request. I wrapped this in an async method. This method takes a url as  parameter. The call for this method is wrapped with a method again, which constructs the actual url.

Imagine the final methodcall looks like this:

```
string resultString = await GetResultString(parameter);
```

Then the following problem occured: I want to send multiple requests at the same time. I've got a list of parameters. I did it like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach(parameter in parameters)
{
    tasks.Add(GetResultString(parameter));
}
List<string> resultStrings = await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
```

That also works fine. But the number of requests is variable. So it could be 10 requests. But it's also possible that you fire 10.000 requests or even 100.000. So I thought about monitoring the progress in a progress bar. But how could I do this? I already had a look on [this](http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress) piece of code but I can't get any idea of how I could use that for my code. I need to raise an event, everytime a task has finished. But how when there is not any callback when a task finished?

Thanks and regards

PS: could somebody tell me how to use copy & paste for code without putting four spaces in front of every single line of code? I couldn't get any help out of the advanced help. I just can't get it work. And I'm sorry that my English is not too perfect. I'm German. :-)

Comment: Copy and paste the code from an editor (i.e Visual Studio). Highlight the text and click on the {} icon in the editor ;)

Comment: When using the code you provided in the link, what was the problem? can you use that code and show us the issue you're having? that code seems pretty clear to me

Comment: I have not yet transformed my code to the code provided in the link. I simply don't know how or where to fire multiple async tasks within that code. Somewhere within there I need to do something like `TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks)`, don't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@McKay and craig1231:** you were right. The code  I provided in the link was perfectly fine, except that an old AsyncCtpLib is used there (well, the post was released at the end of 2010). The code needed to get reworked a bit. But I solved this even before asking this question here.

My problem just was that I didn't understand when the ProgressChangedEvent gets raised.

> Basically, when you instantiate this class [`Progress<T>`, not `EventProgress<T>` since the new AsyncCtpLib releases], it captures the current
>   thread's SynchronizationContext. Then, each time Report is called from
>   inside the TAP method, it raises the ProgressChanged event on the
>   right thread.

The answer was right  there. But thanks, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, First you have to ask yourself what you want. If you have 10,000 requests, and you are able to actually get them to await properly, then they're all in progress. In this particular case, you don't know how done each task is, just how many tasks are completed.

If you have 5 tasks, then a progress time line might look like this:

0------------------------------------------1-23-4---5

Do you want it to say 1 / 5 completed? It seem like 1/5 is misleading, because you're probably almost done?

But other than that, [the link you mentioned](http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress) should cover what it is you want. Why didn't it work?

Comment: Imagine 0.......................12....43....5..(the rest)..1000

It's quite linear still. So I think a progress bar is pretty good still.

`return await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsyncEx( @"http://ancillaryasync.nickbutler.net/Murphy.ashx", progress );` is the async method call for **one** request. If I'd do 1000 requests like this, it's synchronous, still. Because I wait for every single call to finish. I can't find a way to do that with something like `TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: These comments look horrible with code. Sorry about that. I'm pretty new here. Is it alright to answer on your post with "Answer Your Question"? If somebody upvotes it, it appears before your post. That would be confusing, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Schnerrus Sure, answer your own question